# How can I use Angular Typed form feature in FormArray that would be numbers

Tags: angular

For example name field should be string or null.

```
type TypedForm = {
  name: FormControl<string | null>
}
```

I want like this.

```
type TypedForm = {
  roles: FormArray<number[] | null>
}
```

but this isn't valid.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formarray-dynamic-homogenous-collections) help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a typed form approach with **FormArray** that allows you to specify the type of values you want to work with.
Please following steps to create a **FormArray** with numbers or null values.

Step-1: Define the TypedForm interface

```
import { FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

interface TypedForm {
  roles: FormArray<(number | null)[]>
}
```

Step-2: Create the form and form array

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `...` // Your component template
})
export class YourComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      roles: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  get rolesFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('roles') as FormArray;
  }

  addRole(): void {
    this.rolesFormArray.push(this.fb.array([]));
  }
}
```

Step-3: Add form controls dynamically to the FormArray

```
addRole(): void {
  const newRole = this.fb.array([
    new FormControl<number | null>(1),
    new FormControl<number | null>(2),
    new FormControl<number | null>(null)
  ]);

  this.rolesFormArray.push(newRole);
}
```

You have a TypedForm with a FormArray containing arrays of numbers or null values. You can then use this form in your template to bind to your input fields and handle validation accordingly.

hope it helpful..

**Updated Answer**

```
import { AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

interface TypedForm {
  roles: AbstractControl<(number | null)[]>
}
```

Typescript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `...` // Your component template
})
export class YourComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      roles: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }

  get rolesFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('roles') as FormArray;
  }

  addRole(): void {
    const newRole = this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control<number | null>(1),
      this.fb.control<number | null>(2),
      this.fb.control<number | null>(null)
    ]);

    this.rolesFormArray.push(newRole);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. showing error: 
Type '(number | null)[]' does not satisfy the constraint 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.ts(2344)

Comment: @Akib You're right; I made a mistake in the definition of the TypedForm interface. To make it work, we need to use the AbstractControl type for roles instead of FormArray.

answer updated please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can just rely on implicit typing too

```
this.formBuilder.group({
  roles: [[] as number[], []] 
})
```